# Memory access conflict with structs and observer pattern

Tags: swift, memory, model-view-controller, memory-management, observer-pattern

I'm implementing an Observer design pattern on a `Struct` model object. The idea is that I will pass my model down a chain of `UIViewController` and as each controller modifies it, previous controllers will also be updated with changes to the object.

I'm aware this problem could be solved by using a `class` instead of `struct` and modifying the object directly through reference, however I'm trying to learn more about using `structs`.

```
struct ModelObject {
    var data: Int = 0 {
        didSet {
            self.notify()
        }
    }
    private var observers = [ModelObserver]()

    mutating func attachObserver(_ observer: ModelObserver){
        self.observers.append(observer)
    }

    private func notify(){
        for observer in observers {
            observer.modelUpdated(self)
        }
    }
}

protocol ModelObserver {
    var observerID: Int { get }
    func modelUpdated(_ model: ModelObject)
}

class MyViewController : UIViewController, ModelObserver {
    var observerID: Int = 1
    var model = ModelObject()

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        self.model.attachObserver(self)
        self.model.data = 777
    }

    func modelUpdated(_ model: ModelObject) {
        print("received updated model")
        self.model = model //<-- problem code
    }
}
```

Simply put, my model object notifies any observer when `data` changes by calling `notify()`.

My problem right now is memory access: when `data` gets set to `777`, `self.model` becomes exclusively accessed, and when it calls `notify` which calls `modelUpdated` and eventually `self.model = model`, we get an error:

```
Simultaneous accesses to 0x7fd8ee401168, but modification requires exclusive access.
```

How can I solve this memory access issue?

Comment: Why not just use Combine? You also have a reference cycle here but maybe that is offtopic

Comment: @J.Doe What is a Combine? Also where is the reference cycle? Model is a struct not a class, so it doesn't pass references.

Comment: MyViewController holds an instance of something that holds an instance of MyViewController (both strongely), it's a reference cycle, this has nothing to do with classes/structs. Woa, Combine is a new awesome framework for something you want to build, check out WWDC 2019 video's!

Comment: @J.Doe True, my array of observers inside ModelObject needs to weakly retain the view controllers. And also have a remove function. But one problem at a time.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you're observing "a thing," then that "thing" has an identity. It's a particular thing that you're observing. You can't observe the number 4. It's a value; it has no identity. Every 4 is the same as every other 4. Structs are values. They have no identity. You should not try to observe them any more than you'd try to observe an Int (Int is in fact a struct in Swift).

Every time you pass a struct to a function, a copy of that struct is made. So when you say `self.model = model`, you're saying "make a *copy* of model, and assign it to this property." But you're still in an exclusive access block because every time you modify a struct, that also makes a copy.

If you mean to observe ModelObject, then ModelObject should be a reference type, a class. Then you can talk about "this particular ModelObject" rather than "a ModelObject that contains these values, and is indistinguishable from any other ModelObject which contains the same values."

Comment: Thanks, what other factors other than identity, should be considered when using a struct vs class?

Comment: For a good explanation, see https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/choosing_between_structures_and_classes  The important take away is that "Choose Structures by Default" does not mean "most app-level types will be structs." It means, when there are no other compelling factors, use a struct. But there are *often* other compelling factors.